# iOS APNs functionality implementation

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I would like to implement a SMS functionality in my app which includes send message from one user to another.

What I'm trying to do is create a message and send it from mobile to server by HTTP request. Server will receive that message and it will know which user to send to. Then server will push the message back to the destination user using APNs.

Am I doing right? Or is there a more general/standard way to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send SMS, example code:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = @"SMS message here";
    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1(234)567-8910", nil];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

also see [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: How does  this actually answer the users question?